# Discord.js delete X messages

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bulk-delete

How would I delete some messages from a channel with discord.js ? I get the number as an argument for the `delete` command, but I just can't figure out how to actually delete it. I've looked at other questions, the code I saw started with `channel.fetchMessages` which for some reason is not a function anymore. This is the code I currently have: `channel.fetchMessages({ limit: num }).then(messages => channel.bulkDelete(messages));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah okay, I found it. It was `channel.messages.fetch({ limit: num }).then(messages => channel.bulkDelete(messages));`

Answer (score 0):

```
msg.channel.bulkDelete(num)
.then(messages => {msg.channel.send(`** \`${messages.size}/${num}\` messages deleted successfully** `)}).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 10000}))
```

it is also shows the count of deleted messages

if you don't want it this would be enough:

```
msg.channel.bulkDelete(num)
```